# Is this is right way to display json array in php?

Tags: php, json

json display code not working, dont know. where i am wrong.
I am getting json data by url and display it by json code in php.

below are the json object and array.

and php code to display it. but nothing showing.  only blank file.

```json
{ "id": "U1kpDKGutdAQKK5dJEqmvW",

"posData": "23",
"status": "paid",
"price": 1,
"currency": "USD",

"buyerFields": {
"buyerName": "95",
"buyerAddress1": ""
},
"paymentSubtotals": {
"BTC": 25700,
"BCH": 651000
},

"BCH": {
  "USD": 153.6
}
},
"amountPaid": 25800,
}
```

code to display data in php file.

```php
$url = 'data.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$characters = json_decode($data, true); 
foreach ($characters as $character) {
$character["buyerFields"][0]["buyerName"];}
```

Result should be: 95

Comment: '*json display code not working, dont know. where i am wrong.*' - Any errors? What is the expected output?

Comment: You're not doing anything to actually _output_ anything.

Comment: you forget about print/echo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json does not contain any arrays, so you don't need the `foreach` or the `[0]`.

```
$url = 'data.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$character = json_decode($data, true); 
echo $character["buyerFields"]["buyerName"];
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply.  firstly i have used var dump to see the output.  and in buyer fields its display array, so that why.  Thanks its working.